# Why is my file is not opening with ifstream C++?

Tags: c++, arguments, ifstream

Though this is a fairly simple question, I am having trouble opening the file through the `inputFileStream(inputFilePath)`. Could someone just lead me in the correct direction (I'm not here to be given answers for a school assignment)?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

const string ID_LINE = "James McMillan - CS 1336 050 - Assignment 26";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << ID_LINE << endl << endl;

    // guard clause - invalid number of arguments
    if (argc != 3) {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << "<input file path> <output file path>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //extract arguments
    string programPath = argv[0];
    string inputFilePath = argv[1];
    string outputFilePath = argv[2];

    cout << "Program path: " << programPath << endl;
    cout << "Input file path: " << inputFilePath << endl;
    cout << "Output file path: " << outputFilePath << endl << endl;


    cout << "Creating input file stream..." << endl;
    ifstream inputFileStream;
    cout << "Created input file stream." << endl;

    cout << "Opening input file stream: " << inputFilePath << endl;
    inputFileStream.open(inputFilePath);

    if (!inputFileStream.is_open()) {
        cout << "Unable to open input file stream: " << inputFilePath << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to help without the parameters you are passing. In principle this could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution might come from checking if the file exists, try

```
//Add this at the top
#include <experimental/filesystem>
//somewhere in the body
const auto has_the_file = std::experimental::filesystem::exists(inputFilePath);
if (!has_the_file)
{
    std::cout << "Oh No! Can't find" << inputFilePath << std::endl;
}
```

Also instead of parsing the arguments, I would manually set the paths to confirm your expectations on how to specify file paths.